# Debugging a routing issue

Tags: vpn, routing, rras

So I have a weird temporary configuration that we have in place for a migration to AWS. (retiring some old equipment)

I need to pipe web traffic from our current IPs in one datacenter to new ones in another. These IPs are attached to a W2K3 RRAS server, and forwarded through a non-RRAS hardware VPN behind it (on another public IP). That VPN is connected to an AWS VPN, and then in turn routed to a new AWS web server.

Both networks are routing between each other currently, and the web server can be reached from the RRAS server, and vice versa, but public traffic forwarding to the AWS server from outside the RRAS server can not reach the server.

I have verified that, if RRAS is pointed to a NOC based web server, it is publicly accessible, but not when pointed to the new AWS server on the new network.

Obviously, there is a routing issue here. I'm just not sure where: RRAS, NOC VPN, AWS VPN, AWS Server... I'm suspecting RRAS since it is accessible to that point.

Below is the configuration (best I could summarize)

```
|- NOC --------------------------------------------
| Public IP(s) (xx.xx.xx.xx) => RRAS W2K3 (192.168.4.1)
| RRAS Port Forward (xx.xx.xx.xx 80,443) => AWS (172.31.32.5 80,443)
| RRAS Static route (172.0.0.0) => NOC VPN (192.168.4.5)
| NOC VPN (192.168.4.5) => AWS VPN (xx.xx.xx.xx)
| (Decommissioning servers 192.168.4.10...20, gateway 192.168.4.1)
---------------------------------------------------

|- AWS --------------------------------------------
| AWS VPN (xx.xx.xx.xx) => AWS Interface (172.31.32.1)
| AWS VPN Static route (192.168.4.0) => NOC VPN
| (New Servers 172.31.32.5...10, gateway 172.31.32.1)
|--------------------------------------------------
```

And if you're wondering why we're doing this... We don't own our IPs, have hundreds of host names, some out of our direct control, and need to have all traffic resolve to the new servers, even if cached, or delayed to change. (open to suggestions if there is a better way)

Comment: Perform packet captures at all interfaces along the chain and see where things break.

Comment: While I'd love to do that along the chain, the only place we actually have access to do that is on the RRAS server and origination server. I'm going to try Wireshark on those.